# how to Disable BT + WIFI + IR in windows mobile 2005 - C#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

how to Disable BT + WIFI + IR in windows mobile 2005

(working in C#)

thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

Define "Disable".  Do you mean you don't even want the drivers for them loaded?  If so, modify the driver reg keys for each to point to an invalid DLL and restart.

To adjust radio power, take a look at the Radios class in the SDF.  [An example can be found here](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2008/12/23/SDF23ControllingRadioPower.aspx).

Comment: IR isn't a radio, so it would have to be handled differently.  You can turn off the other two Radios using the SDF's Radio class.

Comment: thank's for the help, can i get sample code for how to disable BT  and  WIFI  ?

Comment: I've added a link to an example.